# Returning data from Jinja2 Macro to Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2, folium

I am a beginner with javascript using Python’s folium package to generate an embedded map inside a GUI.

I’m having trouble with Jinja2 javascript templates and exporting data. In the below code a template is defined with a function copy_gps() that is called when an HTML button is pressed. This function works as intended. However, I can’t access copyText.value (the GPS coordinates) where I need to.

Here is the code from the pushbutton:

```js
folium.Marker(
            location=start_location,
            popup=f'<input type="text" value="{start_location[0]}, {start_location[1]}" id="myInput"             name="test1"><button onclick="copy_gps()">Add to Mission</button>',
            icon=folium.Icon(color="red", icon="info-sign"),
            ).add_to(m)
```

And the code from the Jinja2 template:

```js
el = folium.MacroElement().add_to(m)
        el._template = jinja2.Template("""
        
        {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
        
            function copy_gps() {
            
            let copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
            /* document.write(copyText.value); */
            alert(copyText.value);
            return copyText.value;

            }

        
        {% endmacro %}

        {% set a = "hello" %}

        {% set b = script() %}

        """)
```

The copy_gps() function is called properly on the button press, but I want to access the data in the variable copyText within this function, which is in the macro. I've tried to set b equal to the macro script, but when calling in Python:

```js
print(el._template.module.b)
```

... it just prints a string of the function contained in the macro, verbatim, rather than calling the function and printing the returned value.

Is there a way I can get the copyText.value data out from the function within the macro, and print it in a way similar to how

```js
print(el._template.module.a)
```

properly outputs "hello" to the Python console?

Thanks in advance and apologies for poor formatting as this is my first post.